# How can one search for a quick icon on google images without all the stock photo sites coming up on search results?

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations, stock-images

I'm looking for just a very simple icon of just a black and white notepad, but when I use google images its very annoying to have stock photo icon sites to come up where they make you pay for it. Is there a way to filter out all these sites that are polluting the image search results?

Answer (score 2):

You use the [Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=notepad) instead.

If you still need to use Google, any word in your query preceded by the '-' sign is automatically excluded from the search results.

Comment: That's a nice resource Lucian. Bookmarked for later!

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the commercial sites and paid options by selecting results which have been "labeled for reuse". This means they are free and not restricted by license or copyright.

Tools>Usage Rights> Labeled for Reuse

[image]

To find simple black and white ones add "black" to your search query, or select the Black filter.

Also, when looking for simple icons view the Tools>Type>Clip Art or Line Drawing for more options.